# Is AutoMapper mapping EF relationships well?

Tags: entity-framework, c#-3.0, automapper

I am using Entity Framework + AutoMapper to convert the EntityObjects to POCO.

The relationships in EF use `EntityCollection<T>`. The relationships in POCO use `ICollection<T>`. Since `EntityCollection<T> : ICollection<T>`, i thought it would be super easy to cast.

However, when AutoMapper tries to cast the EF `EntityCollection<T>` to POCO, it tries to cast it to a `IList`, it does it everytime it sees a collection. Since `EntityCollection` doesn't implement `IList`, every relationship I have is not being mapped by AutoMapper as expected, and an error is thrown when it tries to do the casting operation.

Have you guys seen this problem before?

Answer (score 1):

AutoMapper only supports these types:
    * IEnumerable
    * IEnumerable
    * ICollection
    * ICollection
    * IList
    * IList
    * List
    * Arrays

Looks like a bug: http://automapper.codeplex.com/workitem/6342